# How can I search a Drupal site with the new Unity lens?

Tags: application-development, lenses, drupal

I'm creating a simple Unity lense for my college site which is based on Drupal, but I don't know how to adapt this command for Drupal API. Please help, it's python.

> We now create our query url, using the Wikipedia opensearch API 
>    url = ("%s/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=25&format=json&search=%s" % (self.wiki, search))

I'm using template to write lense following Wikipedia example http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/. I don't know python but Im familiar with C. This Drupal API calling is the only problem I have to successfully develop a lense. Please help!

Comment: Does Drupal even have a search API you can call?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal does not have a built-in facility for returning search results as JSON. You could use the contributed [services_search](http://drupal.org/project/services_search) module, which exposes a URL on your site such as http://example.com/services/search_node/retrieve.json?keys=whatever.

If you don't want to add the Services module to your site for some reason, you could write a custom module that uses the Drupal function [search_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_data/7) to retrieve search results and then outputs them as JSON.

(Either way, you'll have to add something to your Drupal site, which makes this not an Ubuntu-specific question, so it should probably be moved to the Drupal SE site.)